# AVPlayer not functioning

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, avplayer

I'm trying to use an AVPlayer in objective C in a SpriteKit app, but for some reason despite the URL being defined correctly, I can hear no music.

(This is being run from the gameviewcontroller)

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self prefersStatusBarHidden]; //hopefully stop an annoying bug.
    NSLog(@"Is it on? %d", _playingMusic);
    if(_playingMusic == 1){ //set audio to play if requested

        NSString *soundPath1 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"new_twig_BK2_rehash" ofType:@"mp3"];
        NSURL *soundURL1 = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: soundPath1];
        AVAudioPlayer *BKMPlayer1 = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundURL1 error:nil];
        BKMPlayer1.numberOfLoops = -1; //infinite loops
        [BKMPlayer1 setVolume: 1.0];
        [BKMPlayer1 stop];
        [BKMPlayer1 setCurrentTime:0];
        [BKMPlayer1 play];
    }


}
```

Comment: I would avoid using `AVPlayer`.  Use an `SKAudioNode` instead so that you can keep your music in sync with your scene

Comment: I would, but the music needs to be played from the viewcontroller as its easy to pass variables to saying whether or not the user has pressed the mute button on the main menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating the audio player in `viewDidLoad` method, you should create a `strong` property of audioPlayer

> @property (nonatomic, strong) AVAudioPlayer *BKMPlayer1;

This is because, once the control goes out of the function, the audioPlayer is deallocated by the ARC.